# Logical operators in php

Tags: php, php-5.4

I dont't understand this. If $_GET['action'] is set and action is not "login" or not "messages" I want to doAction().

My non working code:

```
if ( isset($_GET['action']) &&  ($_GET['action'] !== "login" || $_GET['action'] !== "messages") )     {
   doAction();
}
```

If I remove the || it works.

```
if ( isset($_GET['action']) &&  ($_GET['action'] !== "login") ) {
   doAction();
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: `a !== b` means a does **not** equal b

Comment: Yeah. Typo, sorry. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Very strange logical operation.

Comment: And what''s is the testin value for `action` do you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's check execution of your `if` statement:

1. suppose, action is **some_action**
   then `isset($_GET['action'])` **true** and `$_GET['action'] !== "login"` is  **true**

As php has lazy execution (`true` and `true` is `true`) the comparison stopped and your `doAction` executes, fine, just what we need.

2. suppose, action is **login**
   then `isset($_GET['action'])` **true** and `$_GET['action'] !== "login"` is  **false** and `$_GET['action'] !== "messages"` is true (as **login** is definitely not **messages**). So (`true` and (`false` or `true`)) is `true`!
3. finally suppose, action is **messages**
   then `isset($_GET['action'])` **true** and `$_GET['action'] !== "login"` is  **true**. Considering lazy execution your `doAction` runs again.

Okay! Looks like that `doAction` will work always!

Fix for the problem is using `and (&&)` instead of `or (||)` in you `if`

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) 
    && ($_GET['action'] !== "login" && $_GET['action'] !== "messages") ) 
    // that should work properly!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "not equals" operator (`!==`). If you want to test if the value **is** `login` or `messages`, you should use the `==` operator:

```
if ( isset($_GET['action']) && 
     ($_GET['action'] == "login" || $_GET['action'] == "messages") ) {
   doAction();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a typo in my original post. Sorry about that. Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset($_GET['action']) && 
     ($_GET['action'] !== "login" || $_GET['action'] !== "messages") ) {
   doAction();
}
```

Comment: I used not equal operator because question is  If $_GET['action'] is set and action is not "login" or not "messages" and in upper code condition is checking that action is set and action is login or message than do something..

Comment: So edit your answer to include that. I believe what @u_mulder was getting at is that a complete answer on StackOverflow should include both the fixed code and the explanation of how the fixed code works and/or why the code in the question didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When testing conditionals in PHP with ||, PHP will test the conditionals in the order they are written and if one of them is true, the whole conditional evaluates to true. This means that for your code if the value of $_GET['action'] is 'messages', the conditional will evaluate to true:

```
if ( isset($_GET['action']) &&  ($_GET['action'] !== "login" || $_GET['action'] !== "messages") ){
   doAction();
}
```

Because when the interpreter evaluates $_GET['action'] !== "login" and the value of $_GET['action'] is 'messages', the result of that evaluation is true and thus the code in the if block will be executed. I recommend you change your code to:

```
if ( isset($_GET['action']) &&  ($_GET['action'] !== "login" && $_GET['action'] !== "messages") ){
   doAction();
}
```

The || is changed into && and this means that the value of $_GET['action'] cannot be 'login' and it cannot be 'messages'.